# Inserting variables into an input() command in python

Tags: python, variables, input, arguments, raw-input

Hello I am new to the world of programming and I need a bit of help. I was trying to finish some work that I had to do for my Python class and I came across a problem that I couldn't fix and couldn't find answers on the web for. Here is my problem. When I code something like:

```
a = "apples"
t = "tomatoes"
answer = raw_input("Do you prefer eating ", p," or ", t, " ?")
print answer
```

It gives me an error message on line 3 saying: "TypeError: Win32Input() takes at most 2 arguments (6 given)"
What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: If you're new to Python, I'd seriously recommend that you start with Python 3 as it is the more newbie-friendly choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input`'s input is not the same as `print`'s, it takes a string, so you have to create a string by formatting it:

```
answer = raw_input("Do you prefer eating {} or {}?".format(p, t))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: But when i tried to insert your line of code I got this error message:  
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @MatthieuChapeland Looks like you're using Python 2.6, replace `{} or {}` with `{0} or {1}`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I can finish my work now! You've been a great help. :)

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to this site.

Comment: It's ok I found it. Thanks again for your help.